# couchdb cloudant form POST returns error bad

Tags: couchdb, http-post, cloudant

**BACKGROUND:**

https://cloudant.com/for-developers/all_docs/ under "Query by Post" says

"You can also query for a specific set of keys by POSTing a JSON array of keys to the view."

**PROBLEM:**

When attempting to query by POST in an HTML form, the result is an error

```
{"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid UTF-8 JSON"}
```

(see e.g., http://jsfiddle.net/dreftymac/TPb7P/ )

**QUESTION:**

Are the docs on this just not up to date? or is there a reason why POST form submissions produce this error ?

How would one troubleshoot this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloudant accepts HTTP PUT requests with JSON in body. I do not think that HTTP POST with multipart/form-data will work. More information can be found here: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Bulk_Document_API